# Spreadsheet openById How to Traverse all row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to open a Spreadsheet by Id which is not current active Spreadsheet. I am opening it as follows

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my_spreadsheet_id");
  Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

Above code is opening Spreadsheet but I am able to fetch data of first row only. I want to traverse all rows of this SpreadSheet. I could not find any source related to that. Can you help to traverse all rows of a spreadsheet opened by id. 
Here is my full code.

```js
function validate(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RuIXHbzGDR3sJ-ugqXSbQSlxXzqrBOXyopvbkT9QYhQ");
   Logger.log(ss.getName());
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   for (var i in data){
     Logger.log("Iterating through "+i)
     var row = data[i];
    Logger.log("data is "+row[2]); 
   } // This loop is running only for i = 0  while there are 10 rows in my sheet. 

   //Also tried this but gt same result. 

 /*  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows-1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
   for (var i in data){
     Logger.log("Iterating through "+i)
     var row = data[i];
    Logger.log("data is "+row[2]); 
   }*/

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are targetting the correct sheet inside the spreadsheet? With your current code that should be the first sheet (maybe hidden?). Maybe try changing var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; with var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('name-of-sheet") to make sure you are retrieving the data of the correct sheet.

Comment: by making it ss.getSheetByName(ss.getName()) ;it is returning null

Comment: Can you share a copy of the Sheet?

Comment: ss.getName() is the name of the spreadsheet, NOT the name of the sheet/tab you wish to query. You'd have to use the latter ...

Comment: hey, you right I was giving the wrong id to openById method. I fixed it after replacing the correct sheet id from URL.

Comment: Small note: please, [don't use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Why_Use_for...in) `for...in` loop on Arrays, there are dedicated loops and methods for it (`for...of`, `forEach`, `map`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving an answer in case someone faces the same issue. The code was targeting the wrong Sheet as the Spreadsheet Id was wrong.

- [OpenById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)